# Resolve dependencies from inherited classes with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

First of all, let me provide some sample code:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity { }
public class MyEntity : BaseEntity { }
public class MyCustomEntity : BaseEntity { }

public interface IStore<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity { }
public class BaseStore<TEntity> : IStore<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity { }
public class MyCustomEntityStore : BaseStore<MyEntity> { }
```

So basically I have an abstract entity and two derived types. I created a repository class which is hiding all the basic stuff around the BaseEntity (for example fill the "LastModifiedBy" property). But for some cases, I need specific behaviour to saving an entity, so I need to derive from the `BaseStore`, and implement the custom behaviour in `MyCustomEntityStore`. So far, it is easy.

The problem is i would like to use Autofac to resolve dependencies in my application. My goal would be to do this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private readonly IStore<MyEntity> MyEntityStore;
    private readonly IStore<MyCustomEntity> MyCustomEntityStore;

    public SomeClass(IStore<MyEntity> mes, IStore<MyCustomEntity> mces)
    {
        MyEntityStore = mes;
        MyCustomEntityStore = mces;
    }
}
```

I would like to inject an instance of `BaseStore<MyEntity>` to `IStore<MyEntity>` and `MyCustomEntityStore` to `IStore<MyCustomEntity>`. This is working fine with the `MyCustomEntityStore` (which has a concrete implementation derived from the base store), but i do not want to create empty classes just to inherit the `BaseStore<MyEntity>`. I registered my components like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Data")).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Store")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
```

Although these instances can be in the place of these interfaces, Autofac can not resolve the `IStore<MyEntity>`.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with this registering:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseStore<>))
       .As(typeof(IStore<>))
       .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Data"))
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Store"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Can anyone confirm, this is the right way?